# "dotnet new" command fails on fresh installation of OS X 10.11.6 OS X El Capitan

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have installed the dotnet-core for OS X using the dotnet-osx-x64.1.0.0.pkg from the official download section. - https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Running "dotnet new" command gives the below output

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

How to create the basic .net-core project?

---

I have run the below commands on the user directory without success

> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/dotnet"' >> ~/.bashrc

and

Created a vi .bash_profile  and inserted the below command

> export
>   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet

---

Still the below command fails

> dotnet new

---

This is the version of the .net-core I have

> dotnet --version

gives below output

```
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.0.1
  Build    : cee57bf6c981237d80aa1631cfe83cb9ba329f12
```

Comment: current last version is dotnet-dev-osx-x64.1.0.0-preview2-003121 (from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet-osx-x64.1.0.0.pkg` is the package containing just .NET Core, basically the runtime.

In order to develop applications, you need the .NET Core SDK. This is also what the error message you see says:

> Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK […]

The [download website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) also explains the difference as follows:

> You probably only need to download one of these:
>
> - **.NET Core SDK** = Develop apps with .NET Core and the SDK+CLI (Software Development Kit/Command Line Interface) tools
> - **.NET Core** = Run apps with the .NET Core runtime

So, just download the .NET Core SDK package for your platform instead. For mac OS, this currently is [`dotnet-dev-osx-x64.1.0.0-preview2-003121.pkg`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=809124).

---

You can also just follow the instructions on the [.NET Core quickstart page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) which gives you detailed step-by-step instructions on how to get .NET Core running properly.